# phpthumb - disable output

Tags: php, image, class, thumbnails, phpthumb

$phpThumb->GenerateThumbnail() or $phpThumb->RenderToFile() create a output with header information and the thumbnail. How can i disable it? I need to store the thumbnail without a return of the thumbnail on the harddisk.

Here is my code:

```
        require 'class.phpthumb/phpthumb.class.php';
        $phpThumb = new phpThumb();
        $phpThumb->config_temp_directory        = 'thumbnails_c/'; 
        $phpThumb->config_cache_directory       = 'thumbnails_c/'; 
        $phpThumb->config_cache_disable_warning = true;
        $phpThumb->cache_maxage                 = 86400 * 30;
        $phpThumb->cache_maxsize                = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
        $phpThumb->config_cache_force_passthru  = false;            
        $phpThumb->setSourceData($file_data);
        $phpThumb->setParameter('w', 45);
        $phpThumb->setParameter('h', 32);
        $phpThumb->setParameter('zc', 1);
        $phpThumb->setParameter('JPEGquality', 100);
        $phpThumb->setParameter('f', 'jpeg');               

        if ($phpThumb->GenerateThumbnail()) {

            if ($phpThumb->RenderToFile($path_to_the_new_file)) {

                // return the data as an array
                return array(
                    'thumbnail'         => $phpThumb->OutputThumbnail(),
                    'contenttype'       => 'image/jpeg',
                );

            } else {
                // error
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // error
            return false;
        }
```

greetings!

Answer (score 2):

From the [readme](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/docs/phpthumb.readme.txt):

> ## Calling as an object (not using phpThumb.php):
>
> NOTE: most people don't need to and
>   should not do this. If you just want
>   to display resized images, please just
>   use phpThumb.php, not the object mode.
>   **To render output to one (or more)
>   files instead of the browser, you
>   should skip phpThumb.php and
>   instantiate your own object**.
>   Please take a look at
>   [/demo/phpThumb.demo.object.php](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/index.php?source=demo%2FphpThumb.demo.object.php) for
>   details.